# bash for command

Tags: bash, for-loop

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in /home/xxx/sge_jobs_output/split_rCEU_results/*.rCEU.bed
do
intersectBed -a /home/xxx/sge_jobs_output/split_rCEU_results/$i.rCEU.bed -b /home/xxx/sge_jobs_output/split_NA12878_results/$i.NA12878.bed -f 0.90 -r > $i.overlap_90.bed
done
```

However I got the errors like:

```
Error: can't determine file type of '/home/xug/sge_jobs_output/split_NA12878_results//home/xug/sge_jobs_output/split_rCEU_results/chr4.rCEU.bed.NA12878.bed': No such file or directory
```

Seems the computer mixes the two .bed files together, and I don't know why.
thx

Comment: I'm slightly confused, because the output doesn't appear to be valid based on the input (homedir different name, directory path different), and when I try the syntax you have, it WFM.  Can you double check what you're running and show the exact input/output?

Comment: thx. My input comes from two different directory.....Maybe this is the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure, tbh.  However, I suspect $i doesn't contain what you think it does.  Try this, for example: [for i in /tmp/*.tar; do echo $i; done;] If you run that, you get the full path to the files, not just what the * matched.  Therefore, it might return '/tmp/foo.tar'.  I suspect what you are therefore most likely going to want to do is run some sed/awk magic to strip out just the small part of the file name that you're interested in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `i` has the format `/home/xxx/sge_jobs_output/split_rCEU_results/whatever.rCEU.bed`, and you insert it to the file name, which leads to the duplication. It's probably simplest to switch to the directory and use `basename`, like this:

```
pushd /home/xxx/sge_jobs_output/split_rCEU_results
for i in *.rCEU.bed
do
    intersectBed -a $i -b ../../sge_jobs_output/split_NA12878_results/`basename $i .rCEU.bed`.NA12878.bed -f 0.90 -r > `basename $i .NA12878.bed`.overlap_90.bed
done
popd
```

Notice the use of `basename`, with which you can replace the extension of a file: If you have a file called `filename.foo.bar`, `basename filename.foo.bar .foo.bar` returns just `filename`.

Comment: thanks. it works! I don't fully understand what this 'i' refers to!

Comment: If it helps, you can try it in a shell, by just writing 'for i in *; do echo $i; done'. You'll see that 'i' simply contains the file names as the shell matches them.